# justified alignment using TextFormatFlags c#

Tags: c#, winforms, alignment

I want justified alignment of text in a rectangle. I am using `TextFormatFlags.WordBreak`. It properly aligns text to the left, but not to the right side.

The code I'm using for this is:

```
Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(0, 10, 700, 200);
Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(160, 50, 300, 500);

// Specify the text is wrapped.
TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, textBox1.Text, Headerfont, rect1, Color.Black, flags);
```

Comment: [Afaik](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155195/how-to-justify-text-in-a-label/37155609#37155609) you can ony align left, right or center but you can't justify test, unfortunately.

Comment: Why rectangle. Can you use some other control ?

Comment: ohh thanks for quick reply..

Comment: I haven't tried the code, but look at: [Fully justify paragraphs of text in C#](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/10/fully-justify-paragraphs-of-text-in-c/)

Comment: @TnTinMn Thats exactly i was looking for..Thank you so much :)