# VB.net/C#.net How to align text in a textbox left AND right in one line

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, textbox, text-alignment

I wonder whether it is possible to align text in a textbox right AND left in one line like this example:

[image: like this example]

So, I'm not asking for HTML or ASP solutions, but a solution for a standard Windows-Form in VB.net or C#.net. I'm aware of that I could "fake" something similar with two smart-formatted textboxes "appearing" to be one, but I don't want to go this way, because the lines could overlap (like in the example).

If this is simply impossible, I'm also happy if someone could just confirm it.

**Edit:**

I'm also aware of a RichtTextBox control that allows for setting standard tab-stops. But is it possible to set a right-aligned tab-stop, like in Word?

Comment: How exactly should it determine to align left or right? Or do you mean to justify the text?

Comment: Perhaps if you describe why you want to do this alternatives can be suggested, a single textbox like that would be a nightmare to interact with from a user perspective.

Comment: I think you'll have to use a rich textbox

Comment: I suspect you may need to write your own control and owner-draw the text.  Way back, I used to work in typesetting (in the 70s).  The typesetter had a specialized [TAB] character that would inform the line layout engine to "use this space to fully justify the line".  You could do something like that.  You should tag your question with [winforms], by the way

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Could be some kind of seperator character, e.g. the TAB-character, or any other

Comment: @AlexK.: You're right, I forgot to mention this. It is basically a log-output from a program. So on the left side is a status message like "Working on blabla" and after a while the program should place on the right side the result like "OK", or "Error", bus sometimes a little more, like "10.234.345 records processed". Therefore lines could "overlap" and I'm unable to use two seperate textboxes. So in fact, there would never be user input into that textbox, just displaying information.

Comment: There's a TextBoxRenderer class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxrenderer?view=netframework-4.7.2).  That might get you started in the right direction

Comment: Doing that with a two column list box (or even a stripped down DataGridView) might be easier

Comment: Switch to a fixed width font, that way you know how many characters will fit on a line so when you append "xxx" to a new line and want to add "yyy" you can prefix it with a calculated number of spaces.  A bit more work is required for overflow.

Comment: @Flydog57: That would be indeed an idea... But I hoped to get away with less work...

Comment: If anything, it would probably be significantly more work to have to align a bunch of text using a rich textbox (the way you have to select sections by indicies to add formatting is not "hard", but extremely tedious). Like Flydog57 said, something like a table, or a listbox would be much easier because all of the titles will be in column 0 and status messages will be in column 1. And it will probably look neater too.

Comment: [How to justify text in a label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47470191/7444103). Various answers (`C#`). My aswer there deals with both `TextBoxes` (just managed code - somewhat complicated) and `RichTextBoxes` (PInvoking the underlying `RichEdit` Control). Full justification (Block Align).