# RichTextBox cursor keeps changing to IBeam

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, mouse-cursor

I have a readonly `RichTextBox`, with its cursor set to `Arrow`. Even so, when I hover it, the cursor flickers, and switches very quickly between `Arrow` and `IBeam`. How can I make it stay on `Arrow` and not flicker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming this is the WinForms' RichTextBox, because the WPF one doesn't have this *problem*.

The RichTextBox handles `WM_SETCURSOR` messages, to change the Cursor to `Cursors.Hand` if the Mouse Pointer ends up on a Link. A note from the developers:

> RichTextBox uses the `WM_SETCURSOR` message over links to allow us to
> change the cursor to a hand. It does this through a synchronous
> notification message. So we have to pass the message to the DefWndProc
> first, and then, if we receive a notification message in the meantime
> (indicated by changing "LinkCursor", we set it to a hand. Otherwise,
> we call the `WM_SETCURSOR` implementation on Control to set it to the
> user's selection for the RichTextBox's cursor.

You could set the Capture when the Mouse enters the Control's bounds and then release it when the Mouse Pointer leaves the area. The capture needs to be released otherwise, when you first click on another control, the cursor will be set to RichTextBox instead:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!richTextBox1.ClientRectangle.Contains(e.Location)) {
        richTextBox1.Capture = false;
    }
    else if (!richTextBox1.Capture) {
        richTextBox1.Capture = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, until the user clicks on it, then it starts to flicker again.

Comment: Updated, using just the `MouseMove` event.

Comment: I have noticed something. When I hover the mouse over the edges of the `RichTextBox`, the IBeam sometimes appear again for a fraction of a second. Perhaps it's negligible for some people, but it drives me crazy. :D I have tried to capture my screen to show it, but it is so fast that even with 60fps I don't manage to capture it...

Comment: I can't reproduce it, but it may depend on the `ClientRectangle` size. Try to enlarge it: `Rectangle rect = richTextBox1.ClientRectangle; rect.Inflate(4, 4); if (!rect.Contains(e.Location)) (...)`

Comment: Didn't work... However, when I remove the condition and simply write `richTextBox1.Capture = true;` it works. Why do we actually need the condition?

Comment: The reason why you need to release the Capture is explained in the answer. See also what Reza Aghaei wrote. The Capture needs to be released when the Mouse pointer leaves the Control's area, otherwise it generates some mis-behaviours. This is also explained. If you decide to use a Custom Control, see also this: [How to justify text in a label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47470191/7444103). Among the other things, there's a custom RichTextBox that supports Block Align (also known as Full justification). Maybe you have some use for it.

Comment: Your comment helped me understand better what you meant in your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Jimi My comment about capturing is, while you are release the capture when the mouse is outside the control, but when the mouse is over richtextbox, Alt+F4 will not work, because richtextbox has the capture. It's not about releasing capture when mouse leaves.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei  Yes, I know what you meant. My comment was about enforcing the need to release the capture, because the OP was apparently deciding to use just `richTextBox1.Capture = true;` in the event handler.

Answer (score 4):

Jimi's answer works well to stop flickering, but I don't have a good feeling about capturing mouse on mouse move. For example one issue that I see in that solution, is if you set the capture on mouse move, then keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will stop working.

I'd prefer to handle `WndProc` and set the cursor when received `WM_SETCURSOR`:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class ExRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    const int WM_SETCURSOR = 0x0020;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_SETCURSOR)
            Cursor.Current = this.Cursor;
        else
            base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

It stops flickering. Not a perfect solution, but at least those important shortcuts will continue working.

Comment: Why is it not perfect?

Comment: For example when you hover on links, it doesn't show hand.

Comment: Well, from my experience in StackOverflow, you are one of the best WinForms experts on this site (which probably means that you are one of the bests in the world). So I believe in your ability to help the WinForms community with this REALLY important question. :D

Comment: Yes, this is why I do not change the accepted answer. Jimi's answer works just fine for me.

Comment: No need to change at all, unless a perfect answer is shared. I also didn't meant to affect the other answer and the other answer has my vote as well. Just shared another alternative. Specially in case some one wants to have Alt+F4 working even when the mouse is over richtextbox.

Comment: Maybe playing with what is passed (back and forth) when [`DefWndProc` is called](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBox.cs,3669). It takes *some* testing, though.