# C# split text by rectangle

Tags: c#, algorithm, drawing, gdi+, calculation

I have a requirement.

I need to split a string by fitting it into a Rectangle object. I have the string's Font, the regionSize (of size 1780x880), and a default StringFormat object.

Here's my code:

```cs
// file 1
    public static class Utils {
        public static List<string> SplitByRect(string text, 
            Font font, 
            Rectangle layoutRect,
            StringFormat strFormat) {

            var output = new List<string>();

            using (var bmp = new Bitmap(layoutRect.Width, layoutRect.Height)) {
                using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {

                    var strFormatC = (StringFormat)strFormat.Clone();
                    //strFormatC.FormatFlags |= StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces;
                    //strFormatC.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.;
                    //strFormatC.Trimming = StringTrimming.Word;

                    var startIdx = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++) {

                        var currStr = text.Substring(startIdx, i+1-startIdx);
                        var rect = gfx.MeasureString(currStr, font, layoutRect.Size, strFormatC);
                        if (i == text.Length - 1) {
                            output.Add(currStr);
                        } else if (rect.Height >= layoutRect.Height && i+1 < text.Length-1 && char.IsWhiteSpace(text[i+1])) {
                            Console.WriteLine(rect);
                            output.Add(currStr);
                            startIdx = i+1;
                        } 
                    }

                }
            }
            return output;
        }
    }

// file 2

var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent at ipsum bibendum, sollicitudin lacus ut, vehicula mi. Sed diam arcu, rhoncus non ligula non, finibus mollis ante. Mauris a magna est. Nulla et mi ex. Nullam purus nulla, aliquet quis consectetur non, lobortis sit amet lectus. Curabitur a fringilla risus. Proin eget neque quis nibh vehicula vestibulum. Nunc dui dui, venenatis sed nulla non, tincidunt sodales felis. Quisque porttitor est leo, et malesuada lacus feugiat vel. Mauris consequat tortor ipsum, nec congue erat molestie ac. Cras sollicitudin interdum bibendum. Nullam finibus bibendum cursus. Vivamus consequat dolor vel orci scelerisque porta. In vel malesuada diam, eu blandit lectus. Curabitur commodo ex at sapien condimentum finibus. Mauris sit amet sem risus. Aliquam mollis ex sed velit accumsan, eget vehicula leo egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque et tempus magna, eget imperdiet enim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin pellentesque nec est id faucibus. Mauris quis sodales metus, ac varius mi. Curabitur luctus pharetra porta. Nunc fringilla nunc lectus, eu scelerisque eros congue sit amet. Nam volutpat auctor neque vitae pulvinar. Ut semper lorem nulla, non interdum lacus sollicitudin eget. Donec porttitor quam nec diam mollis, vitae aliquam nibh dignissim. Curabitur orci ligula, porta eu tristique at, fermentum quis nisl. Proin dictum consequat quam, nec ultrices massa luctus a. Donec maximus, nisl et mattis pulvinar, erat nunc facilisis ligula, non tempus est risus vulputate leo. Donec faucibus tincidunt ante. Vestibulum imperdiet orci lorem, vulputate scelerisque magna malesuada et. Aenean sit amet odio dignissim, tincidunt enim eu, porta massa. In vulputate mi quis augue condimentum, ut consequat felis cursus. Ut cursus sem in enim fermentum ornare. Cras vitae felis quam. Proin euismod eu sapien tempus porttitor. Praesent imperdiet mauris sed dapibus rutrum. Vivamus mollis, metus ac porttitor varius, magna nisi fringilla diam, eu porta justo mi eget diam. Aliquam et libero quis ante fermentum interdum in quis augue. Aenean ultricies, augue at commodo elementum, ante urna tempus neque, ac ullamcorper risus justo id ligula. In pharetra fermentum tellus, nec commodo felis dignissim sed. Duis faucibus finibus urna, ac pulvinar massa aliquet sit amet. Donec iaculis, odio in elementum rhoncus, dolor nisl sodales diam, sed tincidunt metus quam ut velit. Suspendisse auctor arcu in euismod mollis. ";
            Console.WriteLine(text.Length);

            var font = new Font("Calibri", 48);
            var layoutRect = new Rectangle(new Point(100, 100), new Size(1920, 1080) - new Size(200, 200));
            var strFormat = new StringFormat();

            var output = Utils.SplitByRect(text, font, layoutRect, strFormat);
```

And then I'm drawing each of the strings in *output* using the same Font and in the same regionSize.

Here's the result of the first drawing: 
**Note: Text is padded by 100 pixels on each side. The text rectangle is in the center. The space that needs to be filled up is at the bottom!!**
[image]

But the problem is that the text isn't covering the entire size of the rectangle. This is possibly due to the incorrect size returned by 'MeasureString'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For this kind of thing try to add the typographic parmater to the measurestring call. I don't quite follow the code: do you add any spaces to the lines to fill them up? This will be necessary. I would consider not using regular spaces for this but n-space charcters. They are wider and can be removed if necessary.

Comment: @TaW I'll try to do that. However I don't understand what you mean by adding spaces to lines to fill them up..

Comment: Words will not accidentally fill lines properly. so you need to add extra spaces between them to achive [block alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155195/how-to-justify-text-in-a-label/37155609?r=SearchResults&s=16|23.7979#37155609).

Comment: @TaW In that case no, I haven't done anything to add extra spaces. The text is as it is.

Comment: OK, for this result you actually don't need any code at all; you could use the drawstring overload that take a target rectangle. But for justified output you need a more elaborate code that calulates how many white space characters are missing and them adds them between words.. - (Professional software also sometimes uses  extra thin spaces between letters..)

Comment: Also I couldn't figure out how to 'add the typographic parmater to the measurestring call' :/

Comment: Also, why are empty chars needed to be added? Doesn't draw string calculate the string size with the white spaces in between words?

Comment: Yes it does but that usually will not add up to the full line length. _bibendum_ is too long so it goes to the next line, leaving the previous one short. Or don't you aim at block alignment?? - The param is called `StringFormat.GenericTypographic`

Comment: Using `StringFormat.GenericTypographic` now makes my method return my input text in one line :/

Comment: Also, as for what you're saying it's frankly just flying over my head. It's some complex stuff

Comment: Hm, maybe I didn't get your question right. Are you maybe not talking about the tight border but about the bottom space??

Comment: The border is fine. It's the bottom space that needs to be filled. The full image has a size of 1920x1080 however, there's a margin of 100 pixels for the text.

Comment: I should've mentioned that I realize now, sorry :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198803/discussion-between-tayab-and-taw).

Comment: Hm, if the size and the text are given, what can be used to adapt? The Font size?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [Fully justify paragraphs of text in C#](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/10/fully-justify-paragraphs-of-text-in-c/)

Comment: @JimMischel No, I'm not justifying text. I have deliberately added a margin in the output of 100 pixels as stated. The text rectangle is 100 pixels inside the image from either side. The bottom of the rectangle needs to be filled.

Comment: So you need to change the font size or possibly the line spacing. It's unclear why you're splitting the text into lines when you could just call `Graphics.DrawString`.