# Detecting forced line split in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have an application which analyses data messages in a piped format (HL7), and for that, it has a `DataGridView` that's synced with a `RichTextBox`. Specifically, when you click on a property in the `DataGridView`, it jumps to the corresponding position in the `RichTextBox`, and vice versa.

The `RichTextBox` has word wrap disabled, so I can easily match the lines in the editor to the lines in the actual data.

However, I currently have to deal with messages containing a Base64 dump of a binary file in some parts of it, and the large content is making the rich text box wrap the lines anyway. This makes the calculations mess up, and when matching the returned position in the actual message text, I get wrong data, the analysis fails, and, usually, I get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when the actual next line is shorter than the clicked position on that line.

This is the code:

```
/// <summary>Gets the cursor position as Point, with Y as line number and X as index on that line.</summary>
/// <returns>The cursor position as Point, with Y as line number and X as index on that line</returns>
protected Point GetCursorPosition()
{
    Int32 selectionStart = this.rtxtMessage.SelectionStart;
    Int32 currentLine = this.rtxtMessage.GetLineFromCharIndex(selectionStart);
    Int32 currentPos = selectionStart - this.rtxtMessage.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(currentLine);
    return new Point(currentPos, currentLine);
}
```

Correct behaviour:
[image: Correct]

On this click, the function will return point [28, 4].

Incorrect behaviour on force-wrapped line:
[image: Incorrect]

On this click, the function will return point [6,5], where it should actually be [2813,4]. This causes it to show analysis for the next line, and, as mentioned, if the click is on a location in the line that's beyond the end of that next analysed line, it causes an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Is there any way to compensate for this forced line split? I need to be able to accurately determine the position in the actual text to do the analysis.

Note, the line splits don't seem to be predictable; I don't know what the maximum length is after which it tries to split, or the characters on which it decides a split is possible.

Also note, the two called `RichTextBox` functions, namely `GetLineFromCharIndex` and `GetFirstCharIndexFromLine`, correctly correspond to what's actually shown on the screen... but what's shown on the screen is an incorrect representation of the real data. In fact, it doesn't even correspond to the output of the `RichTextBox`'s own `.Lines` property, which gives me the content in an array of plain text lines.

I'd rather avoid using that `.Lines` property though, since I've noticed that in general, the functions to extract text from the rich text box are rather slow.

Comment: [EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setwordbreakproc) -- [How to Use Word and Line Break Information](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-word-and-line-break-information) (see the warning, even though it doesn't apply here). If the delegate function is not implemented correctly (in a custom control ), you get *random* exceptions. For the delegate pointer, you can use [Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getfunctionpointerfordelegate).

Comment: I suspect that once that once text exceeds the [formatting rectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setrect) of the underlying RichEdit control, it forces a soft line break. Perhaps you could reverse your logic and use the DGV as the navigation source and show 3 stacked RTB's (line before current DGV row, current row, next row)?

Comment: IIRC, if the delegate always returns 0, then you have no line-breaks anywhere.

Comment: @TnTinMn The navigation is actually two-way: clicking in the text jumps to the property analysis in the datagrid, clicking in the datagrid jumps to the start of the selected property in the text. Since the main purpose of the tool is to easily identify the piped data, the text-side navigation is absolutely vital, though.

Comment: @Jimi Oof, that's a bit too deep for me... Interesting idea, but I got no idea how to even send these control messages to a control, all the docs I find for it are C++. Not to mention, the `code` arg for `EditWordBreakProc` means a load of cases need to be handled correctly. I think I'll take my chances looping over `RichTextBox.Lines` for now... hopefully won't give too much of an impact on larger files.

Comment: On a related note, does anyone know if the immutability of the String means a copy is made when just accessing a string length in an array as `rtb.Lines[i].Length`? Because in this case that can be a huge performance difference.

Comment: Much worse than that. The RichEdit control doesn't provide that information (neither the TextBox control does), it just indexes char positions (line breaks are handled internally and it's not public info either, you need to implement your own line break routine to handle those, with an `EditWordBreakDelegate`, as already mentioned), so each time you ask for the `Lines[]` property, [this is what happens](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,682). This prevents you from using that property, if your text is long-ish.

Comment: Note that your [EDITWORDBREAKPROCW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nc-winuser-editwordbreakprocw) callback doesn't need to handle **all** possible cases. The delegate passes in the current char and its index position, along with the `code` value (see the notes in the link I posted). When `code` is `WB_ISDELIMITER = 2`, you can evaluate `lpch[ichCurrent]` (the char in the string at the provided position) and return `0` if you don't want this char to cause a line break (all right, simplified, but that's what it is).

Comment: Yes, I just noticed what the `Lines[]` property does, and it prompted me to optimise things simply by caching that value, and only clearing it on TextChanged events. I think that will be sufficient to keep it responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that if you enable the richedit control's advanced typography option via sending the [EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-settypographyoptions) that the forced wrapping of long text lines does not occur with the `RichTextBox.WordWrap` property set to false.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        richTextBox1.HandleCreated += RTBHandledCreated;
        FillRTB();
    }

    [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    private void RTBHandledCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const Int32 WM_USER = 0x400;
        const Int32 EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS = WM_USER + 202;
        const Int32 EM_GETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS = WM_USER + 203;
        const Int32 TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY = 1;
        const Int32 TO_SIMPLELINEBREAK = 2;
        SendMessage(richTextBox1.Handle, EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS, TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY, TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY);
    }

    private void FillRTB()
    {
        for (Int32 i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText($"Line {i}: ");
            if (i == 1 || i == 3 )
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100000);
                for (Int32 j = 0; j < sb.Capacity; j += 10)
                {
                    for (Int32 k = 0; k <= 9; k++)
                    {
                        sb.Append(k.ToString());
                    }
                }
                richTextBox1.AppendText(sb.ToString());
            }
            if (i != 3)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText($"{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
        }
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
    }

    private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart).ToString();
    }
}
```

Note that I originally mentioned in a comment to the OP's self-answer that a solution using the "Text Object Model" was possible.  On more thorough testing of this technique, I found that it was only accurate for the first line of forced wrapped text, after that it included previous wrapped lines in the determining the line position. Therefore, I am not showing that method.

Comment: Oh wow, this is just so much prettier to look at than that screen full of Base64. Thanks!

Comment: This works great, so happy to find it. There are definitely use cases where you know users don't want or need to scroll out, like base64 in an xml file... I guess Nyerguds and me have the same situation, which .NET does not accommodate!

Comment: @DAG Yea, and the huge horizontal scroll length that this non-wrapping results in was never an issue in my case anyway, since I have the analysis pane, and a click in there can just make the cursor jump to the data blocks after the base64 part. (ps: give some love to the question! People often forget to upvote those too)

Comment: @Nyerguds Done.

Answer (score 0):

In my search for solutions, I found that, as I feared, `RichTextBox.Lines` is not a simple harmless pointer to an array, but in fact an elaborate operation to convert the rich text box contents to plain text, and using that in this situation would severely impact performance.

However, this made me realise that a *lot* of my code throughout the project was *already* accessing that property for random operations, especially in the analysis part that occurs on any line change.

I decided to make a cache variable for that lines array, which is cleared in the `TextChanged` event of the `RichTextBox`. All instances that fetched the lines on the `RichTextBox` were then replaced by a call to this little function:

```
private String[] GetTextboxLines()
{
    if (this.m_LineCache != null)
        return this.m_LineCache;
    String[] lines = this.rtxtMessage.Lines;
    this.m_LineCache = lines;
    return lines;
}
```

This is still rather heavy when simply typing text into the rich text editor, since any key stroke will basically clear the array and then the analyser operation will fetch it again, but since the tool is an analyser first, and only an editor second, this is not a huge issue. And even then, `RichTextBox.Lines` was called multiple times in the analysis following such a key stroke, so overall the result is *still* vastly optimised.

With this system in place, the use of the lines array became viable again in my little `GetCursorPosition()` function, so I adapted it to make use of the new cached value as well:

```
    /// <summary>Gets the cursor position as Point, with Y as line number and X as index on that line.</summary>
    /// <returns>The cursor position as Point, with Y as line number and X as index on that line</returns>
    protected Point GetCursorPosition()
    {
        Int32 selectionStart = this.rtxtMessage.SelectionStart;
        String[] lines = this.GetTextboxLines();
        Int32 nrOfLines = lines.Length;
        Int32 y;
        for (y = 0; y < nrOfLines; y++)
        {
            Int32 lineLen = lines[y].Length;
            // Can be equal if at the very end of a line.
            if (selectionStart <= lineLen)
                return new Point(selectionStart, y);
            // +1 to compensate for the line break character,
            // which is only one byte in a rich text box.
            selectionStart -= (lineLen + 1);
        }
        return new Point(0, nrOfLines - 1);
    }
```

Comment: I was just about to offer you a solution using the [Text Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/text-object-model) and serendipity struck.  The library I used allows enabling the [ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-settypographyoptions) on the RTB; with that enabled, the soft-line breaks do not occur.  If you are interested, I can post that alternative.

Comment: Oh, please do! As I said, this caching was apparently very much needed anyway, but I'd love to just not have the lines breaking at all. It would make the editor look much cleaner.

Comment: @TnTinMn Do you mean [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47470191/7444103) (last paragraph - yes, I know, that's related to full text justification)? Depending on the text structure, it may not be guaranteed that *unexpected* line breaks won't occur. But it may apply.

Comment: @jimi,  I mean setting `TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY` using `EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS`  message.  So I guess the answer is yes.  I'll have to check the RTB source concerning your comments about typography being disabled for a reason.

Comment: @TnTinMn  Don't worry about that. It's not disabled because it doesn't work (or it's *dangerous* :). It's because it's not tested in (and not really designed for) mixed language environment, so you can have quite *weird* results when you have both LTR and RTL (or just RTL, actually) active languages.

Comment: @Jimi Well, that's generally not an issue for me :) I know, never say never, and [be careful with anything related to names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/), but overall, this is an internal test tool, most of our customers are French hospitals, and most of the data sent in these messages isn't even utf-8. It's all technical data, and even most names in there are only included for the sake of human readability, with the real data being the codes given to the employees and patients.