# How can you enforce width limit of a DataGridView column, and ensure text wraps if it exceeds it?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I am having trouble enforcing the column width limit in my DataGridView table. Right now, texts in columns # 1 & 2 can be really long, but column #2 can be exceptionally long where I have to scroll a lot to the right (this is why I don't want to make the width the width of the largest cell). Sometimes, the text cuts off too and unless you hover over it, you won't know there's more text. I used the "Fill" method for the last column, because if the texts in columns #1 and #2 are not that long, column #3 should fill the rest of the space in the DataGridView. This is what it currently looks like:

```
KEY COLUMN |  VALUE COLUMN                                                     | UPDATE COLUMN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fine       | this width can also be very long,but doesn't cut off where it ends|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
fine length| this width can also vary                                          | fine length
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fine width | this width is usually extremely long but cuts off and i have to sc| fine width
```

^ Notice in the last row, for example, the text might cut off and you have to hover over it to read the rest.

This is what I want it to look like (I want there to be a limit to the size of all 3 columns, but columns #1 and #3 should be relatively the same size, and column #2 cell width limit should be a bit larger because the text content can be a bit more. However, all 3 should support wraparound text:

```
KEY COLUMN |  VALUE COLUMN                                | UPDATE COLUMN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fine       | this width can also be very long, but doesn't| 
           | cut off where it ends                        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fine length| this width can also vary                     | fine length
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fine width | this width is usually extremely long but cuts| fine width
           | off and i have to scroll to see the rest of  |
           | the text                                     |
```

This is what I've tried, from reading responses here on Stackoverflow:

```
mydatagrid.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
mydatagrid.Columns[1].Width = 400;
mydatagrid.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
mydatagrid.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
mydatagrid.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

But this is what gives me the first table. Any pointers?

Comment: Usually, `[Column].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;` + `[DataGridView].AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;` makes it look like that. You may want to explicitly set the width of the largest Column (your `"VALUE COLUMN"`). You could set the other columns' `.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill`

Comment: How can I invoke the WrapMode? Even after explicitly setting the width of the largest column + fill and then writing wraptext, the cells still do not wrap text

Comment: I wrote exactly that in my first comment. `[Column]` identifies any Column where that property is applied (e.g., `mydatagrid.Columns[1]`).

Comment: Yes, and that's what I did (I updated my question with the code I used). Even after specifically specifying which cells I want to have the Fill or width property and specifying to wrap text, it still doesn't wrap text (code is updated above)

Comment: Change the `WrapMode` to `Column[1]` only .

Comment: The updated code - is that what you meant? I tried that and it didn't make a difference

Comment: Where's the `AutoSizeRowMode` set?

Comment: Do you mean by adding mydatagrid.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells; ?

Comment: It's in my first comment...

Comment: Whoops missed that, thank you very much! Is there a way to wraptext without spaces? It doesn't wrap text if the text is long and there aren't spaces

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. What spaces? At the end of each line, as a block  align (AKA justification)? Or simply breaking long words? The usual word-wrap mode breaks on the last space before a word that cannot be rendered inside the boundaries. To override the default behavior, you have to draw the text yourself, which implies that you cannot select it. Or something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47470191/7444103), which implies that you have to handle the text copy/cut operations manually.

Comment: Or, you have to replace the default TextBox of a Cell with a RichTextBox and use the formatting options (the Advanced Typographic Options) shown in that link.

Comment: Yes, the issue is that it uses the last space before a word, but sometimes that word is way too long so the cell boundaries cut it off and it's left with ...
Is there a way to ensure that if the word length is way too long, then just use the length of the word for the cell and not cut it off, otherwise use the define cell widths?