# There's any font that doesn't change text len

Tags: vb.net, fonts

I need a font that have the same len no matter if the line contains all 1111 or 8888.
Now I'm using the default VB.NET 2010 font and two lines with the same amount of characters have different len.

Comment: [Monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

Comment: In case you mean [Typographic alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_alignment#Justified), to get the lines **justified**, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37155195/14171304) post.

Comment: No, I need that all the lines with the same amount of character have the same len, so the character #10 is in the same column in every row(line). But thanks for the info, maybe will be helpful in the future.

Comment: Consolas, Courier New, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Any monospace font will do: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font

I personally use Consolas because that is also the default font family used by Visual Studio in the code editor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas

The easiest way to set the font is via the form's designer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.font

Comment: I didn't understood what "monospace" means until now.