# How to align specific text lines in the textBox differently?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been trying to get some text lines from the text file aligned to the right while the rest as per default would stay on the left side. So when the user loads a text file I want the lines with specific values to be aligned to the right.

I am using the TextAlign method, but for some reason, it doesn't work. As well as I have tried to use the PadLeft method pointing directly to the lines that I want to position differently... I got the result but it doesn't look well...

Here is what I have tried so far

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            strFullFillName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(strFullFillName))
            {
                if (line.Contains(profile.Name))
                {
                    textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + line + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + line + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            this.Text = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
        }
```

Comment: Can you describe/show what you mean by… _”but it doesn't look well...”_ … and what would be considered _”well”_?`

Comment: @JohnG if I use the PadLeft method, the text will not be aligned to the right edge of the TextBox, each line will be position differently according to the number of characters/length of that line. I want them next to the right edge of the TextBox, the same as for the Left or default side.

Comment: Well the text box can only be ONE alignment type at a time. Your code is just switching left and right. Whichever one the "last" item is will be the alignment. If you want some left and some right, then you will need to pad some strings left AND some strings right.

Comment: @JohnG I was afraid of getting that answer :) But how about RichTextBox... Is there any difference? I know that it has advanced formatting features...

Comment: See the different RichTextBox paragraph alignments, Left / Right / Block Align (Justify) using the `ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY` options shown here: [How to justify text in a Label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47470191/7444103) in the *About the RichTextBox* section. You probably just need that Custom Control. Using a RichTextBox also gives you the option to set the Text color of specific paragraphs, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `RichTextBox`

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
String[] lines = new String[] { "aaaaaaaa", "bbb", "ccccccccccccccc", "dddddddd", "eeeeeeeeeeee" };
String newline = "\n"; //Environment.NewLine;
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
    rtb.AppendText(lines[i]);
    rtb.AppendText(newline);
    int length = lines[i].Length + newline.Length;
    rtb.Select(index, length);
    int m = (i % 3);
    rtb.SelectionAlignment =  (m == 0 ? HorizontalAlignment.Center : m == 1 ? HorizontalAlignment.Left : HorizontalAlignment.Right);
    index += length;
}

Controls.Add(rtb);
```

Comment: this code is definitely doing something completely different than I need, but apparently showing the Alignment methods... Before I start refactoring the entire class I have to test this code first to see if it really does what it supposes to... Have you tested this code?

Comment: you got me wrong! I don't want "the exact answer" Just asking if you are really sure that this will work... And it's not about 12 lines of code... coz I have many methods for the same class and TextBox... Anyway thanks!

Comment: Asking if someone tested the code they posted is pointless. It's up to you to test it and then accept it or reject it.

Comment: don't get offended, I didn't mean that. I appreciate your effort to help me, and yes, I will test it and let you know if it does a job.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example using a `RichTextBox` that is tailored to fit your current example.

The only variable we need is something to keep track of the number of lines. We will use this `lineIndex` to know where to “start” when selecting a line to align.

For each `line` in the file, append the `line` and a newline to the rich text box.

The `richTextBox.Select` takes two parameters; the starting position and the length.

We can obtain the starting position by getting the first character index of the `lineIndex` (line number in the text box) with…`richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineIndex++)` … as a starting position.

And the length of the selection would be the length of the `line` plus the length of the newline.

After the selection is made, check if the `targetName` is contained in the line and align that line accordingly.

```
int lineIndex = 0;
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(strFullFillName)) {
  richTextBox1.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine);
  richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineIndex++), line.Length + Environment.NewLine.Length);
  if (line.Contains(targetName)) { 
    richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
  }
  else {
    richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
  }
}
```

Good Luck.

Comment: still this implementation is not giving me the right output... Now half of the text is mixed on both sides regardless of tragetName and half is just on the left side. I don't know why, but now I am doubting that something is wrong with those textual files coz they are quite long... I mean it shouldn't be the case but I don't know where to look for the problem and therefore for a solution. Anyway thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

OK, HERE IS THE SOLUTION...

Firstly I replaced TextBox with RichTextBox, I realized it's much faster when it comes to uploading larger textual files.

Secondly, instead of textBox.Text I used the richTextBox.AppendText() method and assigned just 2 parameters string line and Environment.NewLine

```
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            strFullFillName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(strFullFillName))
            {
                if (line.Contains(profile.Name))
                {
                    richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                else
                {
                    richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
            this.Text = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
        }
```

Now it works perfectly!