# how to align some text left and some text right in label or in textbox TextMode="MultiLine" in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show  some text left and some text right side in label or in textbox TextMode="MultiLine" and I have read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/960681/how-to-align-some-text-left-and-some-text-right-in.html) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65527634/how-to-align-specific-text-lines-in-the-textbox-differently) concepts links and I tried the below code

Asp.net :-

```
<div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Left" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Right" />
<asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Left Right" OnClick="Button4_Click" />

<asp:Label ID="txtTelegramChat" BorderStyle="Double" style="overflow: auto" BorderColor="Green" runat="server" Text="" Width="950px" Height="510px"></asp:Label>

</div>
```

C# :-

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

testing(1);


}

   protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
testing(2);
}

protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            testing(3);
        }


        private void testing (int colorIndex)
        {
            
            if (colorIndex == 1)
            {
                txtTelegramChat.Text += "<span style='color:Red;text-align:left;'>Red information...</span><br/><br/>";

        //txtTelegramChat.Text += "<span style='color:Red;'>Red information...</span><br/><br/>";
                //txtTelegramChat.Attributes.Add("style", "text-align:left");
            }
            else if (colorIndex == 2)
            {
                txtTelegramChat.Text += "<span style='color:Green;text-align:right;'>Green information...</span><br/><br/>";
                
        //txtTelegramChat.Text += "<span style='color:Green;'>Green information...</span><br/><br/>";
        //txtTelegramChat.Attributes.Add("style", "text-align:right");
            }
         else if (colorIndex == 3)
            {
                RichTextBox richTextBox1 = new RichTextBox();
                String[] lines = new String[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" };

                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                        richTextBox1.AppendText("Right Text : Hi" + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                        richTextBox1.AppendText("Left Text : Hello" + Environment.NewLine);
                    }

                    txtTelegramChat.Text = richTextBox1.Text;
                }

                //txtTelegramChat.Text = richTextBox1.Text;
            }

        }
```

Like the above code I have tried in different possible ways but I didn't get the my required output

Below example is my required output(I want to show output like this) :-

[image: I want to show output like this]

Suggest me how to achieve this and where I did the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It not clear you want colors. I would probably suggest aliteral control.

so, say like this:

```
     <style>
        .myshadow {box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px 0px gray}
        .myshadow {border-radius:10px}
        .myshadow {border:solid 1px;padding:4px;border-color:black}
        .myshadow {background-color:aliceblue;display:inline-block;margin-bottom:10px}
    </style>


    <div style="width:50%;height:400px;border:solid 1px black;overflow:auto;padding:8px">

        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server">
        </asp:Literal>

    </div>
```

And now code like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadText();
    }

    void LoadText()
    {
        string MyText = "";

        // add some red text to box

        MyText += AddText("This is some red text", "red");

        MyText += AddText("This is some Blue text", "blue","right");

        MyText += AddText("The Matrix is watching you", "Green");
        MyText += AddText("Knock knock....", "Green");
        MyText += AddText("Follow the White Rabbit", "Green");
        MyText += @"<br/>";   // skip (blank line)

        MyText += AddText("This is some red text", "Red","left",false);
        MyText += AddText(" and ", "Black","left",false);
        MyText += AddText("Some blue text on the same line", "Blue");

        MyText += AddText("left text on same line", "blue", "left", false);
        MyText += AddText("right text on same line", "red", "right");

        Literal1.Text = MyText;
    }

    string AddText(string strText, string scolor, string LeftRight = "left", bool NewLine = true)
    {
        string sResult = "";
        sResult = 
            string.Format(@"<div style='font-size:large;color:{0};float:{1}' class='myshadow' >",
            scolor,LeftRight) + strText + @"</div>";

        // add new line???
        if (NewLine)
            sResult += @"<div style='clear:both'></div>";

        return sResult;
    }
```

And we now get this:

[image]