# change line Spacing Between the lines in TextBox VB.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, line, line-spacing

Please Help me to Change Line Spacing in Text Box on VB.Net!

I have a MultiLine TextBox and want to change line Spacing Between the lines

Do I have to use another control?

Can't do this in the text box?

Comment: It appears that there's no managed API for that. [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/202448/changing-the-line-spacing-in-a-richtextbox-control)'s is a demonstration of how to do it with a `RichTextBox`.

Comment: If you're interested in setting the RichEdit (RichTextBox) Control's options through `PARAFORMAT`, I suggest to enable the `AdvancedTypographicsOption` as show here: [How to justify text in a label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47470191/7444103). It also shows how to justify (block align) text in a RichTextBox (version `RICHEDIT50W`).