# textbox padding in winform application

Tags: winforms

I want to set the position of my text in textbox and I don not know how, since there is no 'padding' property I can change. I don not want use panel to adjust my text
is there any other way? can I change the font margin in font editor software like fontCreator?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you trying to do? -- Did you test the RichTextBox Control? Can its `*Indent*` properties work for you?

Comment: I want my text to fill the textbox and I be able to modify this distance. I have not tried RichTextBox

Comment: What does *fill the TextBox* mean? Is it a multiline TextBox? Or do you want to increase the space between letters in a single line TextBox? If you want to justify multiline text, try this Custom RichTextBox Control: [How to justify text in a label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47470191/7444103) (yep, the question was about a Label) - There are other answers there that maybe you can use in your context. -- You should post the code you have, so it's more clear what you're trying to do. Also the language you're using (tag the question accordingly, you forgot that).

Comment: Do you mean increasing the left and/or right margins of a normal `TextBox` (IIRC the _formatting_ rectangle) and maybe the top and/or bottom margins of a multiline one? If so, yes its possible. You need to p/invoke `SendMessage` function to `EM_GETRECT`, adjust the formatting rectangle, and `SendMessage` again to `EM_SETRECT`. Please confirm if that is what you need. Don't forget to add the language tag.